# Unable to send file from client/server -socket pgm-Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

From client I am trying to send a txt file to server.

client.py

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 8340
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

server_addr = (TCP_IP, TCP_PORT)

c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
c.connect(server_addr)

file = open(r"C:\Users\sakthi\Desktop\Hi.txt",'r')

transfer = file.read(BUFFER_SIZE)

while transfer:
    c.send(transfer.encode())
    transfer = file.read(1024)

print (s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode())

c.close()
```

Server.py

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 8340
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()

final = open(r"C:\Users\sakthi\Desktop\final.txt", 'a+')

while 1:
    print('Connection address:', addr)
    r = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
    if not r:break
    final.write(r)
    print("received data:", r)

k="file received"

conn.send(k.encode())

conn.close()
```

Once the file is received, server will send message "file received" to client. 
Client will print the message "file received" and close the connection

When I run the code, server.py is not coming out of while loop

```
while 1:
    print('Connection address:', addr)
    r = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
    if not r:break
    final.write(r)
    print("received data:", r)
```

`r = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()` keeps listening for new messages, but the client has transferred all messages.

size of the file is `1.14 KB`.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong in my program?

Comment: I am using   "if not r:break" to come out of the loop. So if empty data is received, it will break the while loop

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution

Note our statement that recv() blocks until either there is data available to be read or the sender has closed the connection holds only if the socket is in blocking mode. That mode is the default, but we can change a socket to nonblocking mode by calling setblocking() with argument 0.

I have modified the server.py

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 8340
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()

conn.setblocking(0)

final = open(r"C:\Users\sakthi\Desktop\final.txt", 'a+')

while 1:
    try:
        print('Connection address:', addr)
        r = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
        final.write(r)
        print("received data:", r)
    except:
        break

k="file received"

conn.send(k.encode())

conn.close()
```

Now I am able to receive the file and send message "file received" to client and connection is closed.

[non-blocking socket,error is always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647046/non-blocking-socket-error-is-always)

http://www.mws.cz/files/PyNet.pdf